# Access Ember.js API response

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to ember and wondering why I can't access the response object I get from an API I'm querying.

The API is responding with a json object. When I `console.log` the resonse, I get the following:

```
Class {isFulfilled: true, isRejected: false, content: (...), __ember1400833841805: "ember4895", __nextSuper: undefined…}
__ember1400833841805: "ember4895"
__ember1400833841805_meta: Object
__nextSuper: undefined
content: (...)
get content: function () {
set content: function (value) {
isFulfilled: true
isRejected: false
__proto__: Object
```

The json which I'm awaiting is an array of hashes, containing ID's and titles.

How would I for instance get the first title out of this object? Thanks!

**Update**
This is the response I get with the code from @redjam13.

```
Class {type: function, content: (...), store: Class, isLoaded: true, isUpdating: false…}
__ember1400846275413: "ember2104"
__ember1400846275413_meta: Object
__nextSuper: undefined
arrangedContent: (...)
content: (...)
get content: function () {
set content: function (value) {
isLoaded: true
isUpdating: false
store: Class
type: Network.Tag
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Including some code would make this easier to answer.

Do you perhaps need to fulfil the Promise with something like this:

```
this.store.findAll('whatever').then (
    function (response) {
        // response should be your json object
    },
    function(reason) {
        // error
    }
);
```

See this article: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm doing the API from a route. What else relevant could I say? I postet the response I get with you code as an update in my question.

Comment: You've posted the response, yes but not the actual code you have to try and make the request / get the response. If we could see this, it would be easier to understand what you're trying to do / where things are going wrong.